# Get remote action query results without namespace

Tags: managed-package, javascript-remoting, remote-action, namespace

I'm working in a managed package and I want to use the less references to the namespace (CI proposes ).

For now I would like to know if it's possible to get records from my controller in my javascript code without the namespace in a remote action. for example:

Method in controller:

```
@RemoteAction
public String getAccountInformation(){
    return JSON.serialize([Select Id,Name,my_custom_field from Account]);
}
```

function in  my javascript file:

```
function loadAccounts(){
    my_namespace.MyController.getAccountInformation(function(result,event){
        if(event.status){
            var array = JSON.parse(result.replace(/(&quot\;)/g,"\""));
            //Here My loop over the array
            //here my array returns namespace__my_custom_field **************   
        }
    });
}
```

I would like something that returns the value without to create and assign the values to a wrapper class in the controller.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is a use case for apex:remoteObjects. Have you tried that instead?

Answer (score 0):

To make your visualforce page Javascript remoting independent of namespace use the below syntax

```
 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.getAccountInformation}',
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {

            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

            } else {

            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
```

Here is the document from SFDC for [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_namespaces.htm) .As per docs the namespace is automatically taken care.

However if you have custom field names I think you will need to still handle the field namespaces ,In that case you can write an apex class to get the namespace and use a remote action first to get the namespace and store as a global variable and then use that to append to all the custom fields .